# Write HTML to page in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, razor

I have some HTML stored in the database that looks exactly like this:

```
&lt;strong&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"&gt;Maintenance scheduled &lt;/a&gt;&lt;/strong&gt;tomorrow
```

I want to output that to the Razor view properly formatted as HTML. I do not want to see the `<` and `>`, I just want the HTML.

You can see from this snippet that I've tried several different things:

```
div id="maintenanceMessage">
            @*@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(sysSettings.MaintenanceMessage)*@
            @*@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode((new HtmlString(sysSettings.MaintenanceMessage)).ToString())*@
            @Html.Raw(sysSettings.MaintenanceMessage)
</div>
```

But in every case it keeps showing it as text:

```
<strong><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Maintenance scheduled </a></strong>tomorrow
```

and not formatted HTML. 
I'm not sure what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(sysSettings.MaintenanceMessage))
```

Comment: need to be careful using this though, if the content is user generated, you will be wide open to XSS attacks

Comment: Excellent. That did the trick. In this case, only the highest level admins have access to that field, and the message would only show in the backend of the site. But, warning noted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if you replace the ascii before sending it to the view does it work. we send our strings through these

```
public string Decode(string value)
    {
        return (value)
            .Replace("&quot;", "\"")
            .Replace("&lt;", "<")
            .Replace("&gt;", ">");
    }

    public string Encode(string value)
    {
        return (value)
          .Replace("\"", "&quot;")
          .Replace("'", "''")
          .Replace("<", "&lt;")
          .Replace(">", "&gt;");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your stored content. Maybe when you tried to store it in the database, it got the special HTML characters replaced with encoding characters. For example:

In the Unicode format, every **<** sign from the HTML tags would be replaced with the **&#60;** character.

It's better to store the raw HTML then the encoded HTML, so you won't have to deal with Coding/Encoding conversions.